# How To Hide Column in jQgrid but show this Column in Add/Edit panel

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I want a form of control I use. But the number of fields that are too high. How can I display the grid, but only some of the fields in the form add/edit popup panel show all fields ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
colModel:[
    {
        name:'email',
        label: 'E-mail',
        editable: true,
        hidden: true,
        editrules: {edithidden: true}
    }
```

The `E-mail` column will not appear in the grid but it will be present in the edit dialog.

BTW to achieve the opposite (display in the grid but **not** in the edit dialog):

```
colModel:[
    {
        name:'email',
        label: 'E-mail',
        editable: false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden property for your column

example:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="a_unid" index="a_unid" title="Ref id"  hidden="true"/>
```